# Collider2d and mouse Drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.isTrigger != true && other.CompareTag("Mouse"))
    {
        if (image.activeSelf == false)
        {
            image.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a code like this.My problem is when I drag mouse to move Object with tag "Mouse" into collider, if I drag mouse too fast,Collider cannot catch Object "Mouse" and some image cannot active.Any one can help me with this.

Comment: You might have some unnecessary code in the example you gave here. I tried this in a test project and it worked for me, but I just used `if (other.CompareTag("Mouse"))` as my only logic before setting the `image` object to active. You could then use `OnTriggerExit2D` to set the image back to false.

Answer (score 0):

colliders are not very good at detecting "crossings" , but they detect very well if something is inside something else.

Is the collider a small or narrow object and are you trying to drag the mouse across the collider? If that happens you could widen the collider object to make sure that the mouse is still inisde the collider when caught. So you actually check if the mouse is in the collider or out and not if it happened to pass the collider.